# What's the logic behind the && (and) working while || (or ) doesn't in this code

Tags: javascript

```
var answer = prompt("are we there yet")

while(answer.indexOf("yes") === -1 && answer.indexOf("yeah") === -1 ){
    var answer = prompt("are we there yet")
}

alert("yay we made it");
```

&& works when both parts are true, in this case, if we write yes OR yeah it will work, if we write only yes while it works, it's "false" because we didn't write yes AND yeah in the same prompt.

Well obviously i'm wrong. Why doesn't OR work when one of them just needs to be true, I would only need to write either yes or yeah for it to work.

Comment: `indexOf() === -1` means it doesn't exist.  I think your after `answer.indexOf("yes") !== -1 || answer.indexOf("yeah") !== -1`

Comment: As keith mentions. In addition to changing the logic operator, you will also have to invert the value comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

The logic there is little wrong, when you write while statement

```
while(answer.indexOf("yes") === -1 && answer.indexOf("yeah") === -1 )
```

here while executes it's body when conditional inside is true

```
while(*true*) => do something
```

when you type for example yes in prompt, while takes false as conditional because

`(true && false) => false`
that means while doesn't execute it's body any more.

when you write || instead of &&

`(true || false) => true` so while statement continues to execute body

So the write code would be

```
while(answer.indexOf("yes") !== -1 || answer.indexOf("yeah") !== -1)
```